# Spring + Hibernate Конфигурации

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource] for bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource] for bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource] for bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource] for bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource
```

Вроде как делаю все правильно, а получается вот такое
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource] for bean with name 'txManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc[/url] -->
    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop[/url] -->
    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- [url]https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc[/url] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Hibernate JPA Hello World Application</display-name>

<!-- Configuration file for the root application context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Configuration for the DispatcherServlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="Site" />
    <property name="hibernate.properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users_and_music" />
    <property name="username" value="zarpom" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource">
```

Класс [`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Datasource`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html) не является transaction manager.

Вам нужен [`JpaTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) или [`HibernateTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html). Последний должен находиться в пакете, соответсвующем вашей версии Hibernate.

Если вы хотели использовать `tomcat-jdbc` пул, то его и надо было описывать как `DataSource`.